# JQuery Dialog Initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, initialization, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I continue getting this error when I click the close button (which doesn't close) on my JQuery Dialog:

*Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'*

in Chrome Tools after attempting a few of the suggested fixes on StackOverflow in other questions.

Can anybody point out where I am not structuring the dialog correctly to cause this error?

live fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PTXZV/)

```
$(document).ready(function fooDialog() {

    $('#fooChartDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 1000,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Drill Down Report": function () {
                window.open('example.com');
            },
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        open: function () {
            $('#fooChartDialog').load($('#fooChartDialog').data('url'), function () {
                fooChartLoad()
            });
        },
        title: 'Customer Satisfaction Chart',
        modal: true
    });

    $('#fooChartButton').click(function () {
        $('#fooChartDialog').dialog("open")
    });
});
```

Comment: you have extra commas after `modal: true,` `"Close": function () {
                $('this').dialog("close");
            },`

Comment: Thanks, I removed the commas however I still have a problem when clicking the close button of the dialog not closing and throwing an error.

Comment: @Alexander did you even find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$(this).dialog("close");` instead of `$('this').dialog("close");`

current object should be referenced by **`$(this)`** not by `$('this')`

Comment: @Alexander I can't see any error in fiddle. It's working fine by David's solution.

Comment: Same, I changed the reference for $(this) it works in the fiddle, but not on my local so I believe there is a deeper issue on my side. Thank you both.